# Creating website mirrors using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm wonder if is possible to create website mirror using node.js ?

I want to download any website then serve "mirror" from my server.
I need that because I want to evaluate my JavaScript code. (Inject my appliaction)

Use case:

1. User run my app using node.js
2. User go to localhost and see prompt with message "Please provide URL" , user provide url
3. Magic <- I don't know how to do that
4. User seeing cloned website with injected my application on localhost

example: https://proxy-nl.hide.me/go.php?u=5tQh%2FJXE0YTNU1lkmF2G8%2B5M88s%3D&b=5&f=norefer

There is any tool for node.js to do that easly ?

Comment: http://phantomjs.org/

Comment: @zerkms Why you thinking I want to steal ?

Comment: "User seeing cloned website with injected my application" --- an arbitrary site disallows to reproduce completely or partially their contents without their consent.

Comment: @zerkms I provided example proxy-nl.hide.me this app stealing?

Comment: I think he's talking about proxy server.

Comment: I think it might help https://github.com/nfriedly/node-unblocker